# java.lang.IllegalStateException when insert into database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase` when insert into `TABLE_STOCKUNIT`. When you insert into `TABLE_PRODUCT`, there is no such problem.Tell me, please, why the problem arises, because `db.close()` is called after the `db.insert()`?

```
 public long addProduct(ProductDescription product, int quantity) {
    long rows;
    SQLiteDatabase db=null;
        try {
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
            value.put("producttype_id", 0);
            value.put("barCode", product.getId());
            value.put("name", product.getName());
            value.put("value", product.getPrice());
            value.put("measure_id", 0);
            value.put("precision", 0);
            rows = db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCT, null, value);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }

        try {
            ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
            value.put("stock_id", 0);
            value.put("product_id", getProductByBarCode(product.getId()).getKey());
            value.put("qty", quantity);
            long row = db.insert(TABLE_STOCKUNIT, null, value); //java.lang.IllegalStateException


            db.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -2;
        }


    return rows; // return rows inserted.
}
```

Comment: You haven't defined what `db` is in the second `try` block

Comment: I guess somewhere else closing the database before the second one is done. Try to add `db.isOpen()` for debuging.

Comment: @R2R don't see how this one is a dupe, since its an obvious typo

Comment: What does `getProductByBarCode()` do?

Comment: @laalto, Yes, the problem was in `getProductByBarCode()`. there too db.close.Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronize ur first SQLiteDatabase db insertion like this,to make sure this invocation is given the top most priority by the main thread and every other operation by any other thread is halted(if any) until the insertion takes place:

```
synchronized(db) {
      try {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
        value.put("producttype_id", 0);
        value.put("barCode", product.getId());
        value.put("name", product.getName());
        value.put("value", product.getPrice());
        value.put("measure_id", 0);
        value.put("precision", 0);
        rows = db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCT, null, value);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }

    }
```